Cannot backup Pixel 6a
I forgot my passcode the other day (Pixel 6a, Android 14) and I was planning to backup my phone, reset my phone, then put all the data back into the phone. I was planning to use ADB, but then I realized that USB Debugging is not enabled. The only way to really use ADB at this point is to go into recovery mode and selected the "Install update from ADB" option,which is what I did. then I put in this code. "adb backup -apk -obb -shared -all -system -f backup.ab", but it returned this error. "adb: unable to connect for backup: closed"
Any fixes/Is it possible to do it in sideload mode? If not then just tell me

I use Pixel 6a
Firstly, sorry but the only way out for you is to try to recall the password. Or use Google backup to restore (if you backed up)
Next, coming to your questions:

In recovery or sideload mode adb is very restricted and adb backup won't work. IIRC, so is the case with adb pull /sdcard/

Even in normal mode, adb backup is a poor choice. See Does adb backup/restore still work because it says it's deprecated?. In addition to the problems with apps targeting Android 12 and above, banking apps and other apps that depend on Android Keystore
will not be restored correctly (this is the case with rooted backup methods too)

Also note that the backup command tried by you would have failed if the device is not rooted. See accepted answer here How do I know when "adb backup" is finished? (I am presuming your device isn't rooted, else you would have a backup using rooted apps on your PC/USB/cloud). Even if your device is rooted, and you took a backup using adb, it would be useless because it would be encrypted. How are you going to decrypt?


